# Page refreshes the php variable on reload

Tags: php

i am working on a website where user is allowed to add a product to cart through this button

```
    <button name="add_to_cart" >Add to cart</button>
```

when the button is clicked it adds the product into a session variable

```
if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart']))
        {
            $_SESSION[$p_det][$_SESSION['p_val']] = $_POST['add_to_cart'];           
            $_SESSION['p_val']++;
        }
```

> 'p_val' is initially equal to 0 (p_val is stored in function.php tab
>   included in index.php)
>
> $p_det is equal to "product_details"

when i press the button the session variable is updated and the value p_val is incremented, but after i try to add another value in the $_session[$p_det][p_val] is overwritten by the new click of button, i don't want it to be over written instead it should be added as the second variable of the cart (i have tried the keyword static already), in my observation when the page reloads  on the button click it refreshes the $_session['p_val'] variable back to 0, i have tried basic php variable already in place of $_session['p_val'].

Comment: `$_SESSION[$p_det][] = $_POST['add_to_cart'];` ?

Comment: I think your issue is that you're setting `p_val` to zero in your `function.php` as you mentioned, which is reloaded when you reload the page. You could check if it is set in that function I believe and set it to 0 if it isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

To compliment the answers in the above answer, you could also do this:

In your function.php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['p_val']))
{
    $_SESSION['p_val'] = 0;
}
```

Change your other code to this so it is one less line. This will increment after, so your first value will be 0.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart']))
{
    $_SESSION[$p_det][$_SESSION['p_val']++] = $_POST['add_to_cart'];           
}
```

But, if you aren't using `$_SESSION['p_val']` elsewhere, it's best to follow the answer above and use `$_SESSION[$p_det][]` instead.